# Using XMLHttpRequest and post

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest

The form works fine with the parameter action= "(path to php file)", but when I try to use the XMLHttpRequest instead I don't get any response.
The reason I want to use XMLHttpRequest is that I want to save the response (text) into an array.

```js
function receivedData(serverReply) {
        if (serverReply.readyState == 4 && serverReply.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('main').innerText = serverReply.responseText;
            }
        else {
            console.debug('problem ' + serverReply.errorCode);
        }
    }

    function sendRequest() {
        let myForm = new FormData(document.getElementById('timeDateFormId'));
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "get3.php");
        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () { receivedData(xhr) }, false);
        xhr.send(myForm);
    }

    document.getElementById('timeDateFormId').addEventListener('submit', sendRequest, false)
```

```html
<form id="timeDateFormId" method="post">
    <label>From date (YYYYMMDD)</label>
    <input type="text" name="fDate">
    <br>
    <label>To date (YYYYMMDD)</label>
    <input type="text" name="tDate">
    <br>
    <label>From time (HH:MM)</label>
    <input type="text" name="fTime">
    <br>
    <label>To time (HH:MM)</label>
    <input type="text" name="tTime">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: I set up the form only for some testing, but thanks for reminding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `sendRequest` method when you submit the form.

Submitting the form causes the browser to navigate to the response from the form submission.

This loads a new page which cancels the Ajax request.

---

You need to prevent the default behaviour of form submission if you want to run JavaScript *instead*.

```
function sendRequest(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // etc
```